# PHP Paypal integration test account

Tags: php, paypal, integration-testing

I am going to work on a project that involves Paypal function. My question what kind of account do I need to do the test? Do I need merchant account?

And if you also have a good reference site please share it here.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need both. The merchant/seller account is needed as the payment receiver. Buyer account is needed to do payment to seller.

PayPal have a complete documentation, see it all [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation#wps). Important documentation to help you start quickly:

1. [PayPal Sandbox documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_testing_sandbox).
2. [IPN Introduction](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro).
3. [HTML Form Basics for Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics)
4. [Sample Code](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code)

If you using PHP, you might want to consider using [this library](http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html) to help you integrate PayPal Website Payment Standard easily.

Answer (score 1):

What you need depends on how you're integrating, but in general it's useful to have both a buyer and merchant account.  Signing up for both is very easy on [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com) so it shouldn't be a problem setting up as many buyer/seller sandbox accounts as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can check/ read all about paypal integration on the following link.

http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration